# try reaching local network IP and the wrong IP always comes up

Tags: networking, apache2, localhost

Ubuntu 20.04 - VirtualBox 6.1.18
The kernel was 5.6 and now updated to 5.11 - that update didn't help fix this.
I'm using bridged mode Network setup

When using

```
ip a
```

I see:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e5:43:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.61/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 84678sec preferred_lft 84678sec
    inet6 fe80::110e:5994:33d1:45fe/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, if I put 192.168.1.61 in the browser, hoping to see the local apache2 install, it always tries to go to 192.168.1.62 instead and then says it's unreachable.

I'm not that great with ubuntu administration yet but have set up mod rewrite to allow Wordpress to use permalinks.

All was working fine for a while and now today I can't reach localhost at all. What can I review to see what went wrong?